# Simple Python TCP server not working on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2, firewall

I am trying to run a simple Python TCP server on my EC2, listening on port 6666.  I've created an inbound TCP firewall rule to open port 6666, and there are no restrictions on outgoing ports.

I cannot connect to my instance from the outside world however, testing with telnet or netcat can never make the connection.  Things do work if I make a connection from localhost however.

Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import socket


    TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
    TCP_PORT = 6666
    BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(1)

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connection address:', addr
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        print "received data:", data
        conn.send(data)  # echo
    conn.close()
```

Comment: How did you add the inbound TCP firewall rule?  Did you modify the Security Group associated with this instance?

Comment: Are you using the internal or external EC2 address when trying to contact your server from outside?

Comment: I am using the ip address displayed from "ifconfig eth0"

Comment: And yes, I modified the default security group for the instance.

Answer (score 10):

Your TCP_IP is only listening locally because you set your listening IP to 127.0.0.1.
Set `TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0"` and it will listen on "all" interfaces including your externally-facing IP.

Comment: may be you can see the ip of the interface that you want to expose and assign to the TCP_IP constant

Comment: If you do assign the actual IP for the externally-facing IP you would want to make sure that it is a static IP address. 0.0.0.0 is just the quickest way to solve the issue since there is only 1 interface that his firewall rule implies anyway.

Comment: Thanks Max, good suggestion, but I still can't reach it.  There must be something on AWS itself getting in the way.

Comment: Make sure that in the security group settings that your source IP address is set correctly as your WAN IP address in CIDR notation. For testing purposes you can set the source IP address in the firewall rule to 0.0.0.0/0 which will open port 6666 to everyone (so you won't use that in production). If your EC2 instance is not built by Amazon you might want to run "sudo iptables -L" to see if there are local firewall rules blocking you as well.